# Norway jobs rss feed is pushing nonrelated feeds

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, feed

I'm subscribing to Stack Overflow Norway jobs and last week it has been receiving jobs entries from USA. I'm not having similar issues with Stack Overflow Denmark jobs.

@Jason Punyon
the URL for the feed: http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/default.asp?pg=pgFeed&feed=11602785

Comment: Do the USA jobs that are showing up allow telecommuting?

Comment: Or teleportation :-)

Comment: Can you post the URL you're using for the feed?

Comment: @Jason see his edit

Comment: Teleportation is in progress but I am not at liberty to go further.

For telecommuting, there is a checkbox in the search form on the right: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?telecommute=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the issue -- our new geocoding is looking for "NO" instead of "Norway". I'll see what we can do to deal with that.

In the meantime, you might just do a search for "Norway" on th new site, and click the RSS icon. That'll give you a new URL for your RSS reader.

Comment: This should be better now -- "legacy" RSS URL's should redirect to more meaningful searches. The above advice still applies, you can always grab a new RSS feed based on a search.